# Restarted phone now its stuck in a loop

Tags: iphone

I restarted my iPhone 6s and it went to the apple logo then went off and will repeatedly do so when on charge. It is a black screen unless I click the power button when off the charger in which case it also only shows the apple symbol. Granted it's three years old. Is this the end of its life or something I can fix ???

Answer (score 1):

1. Force restart it
    To force restart or hard reset your device, press and hold the
    Sleep/Wake and Home buttons simultaneously for at least ten seconds.
    After about ten seconds, you should see the Apple logo and can
    release the buttons.
2. If you have the iTunes app at your PC/iMac?? Restore your
    iPhone through iTunes. S O S ..before restoring it you have to back
    it up to iTunes or iCloud.